# Modify events properties inside a eventDragStart callback

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm struggling to implement a special behavior in an application based upon Fullcalendar.

The application is an appointment scheduler :

- there are several types of appointments
- there are time slots (background events), on which you can drag and drop some appointments
- those time slots accepts only some types of appointments (for each time slot, user can choose which types are allowed or not)

To improve the UX, what I'd like to do is the following :

- When the user starts dragging an appointment, the time slots which accepts this appointment's type should turned into green. And the time slots which are forbidden should turn into red.
- When the drag stops, all the time slots should turn back to blue.

I tried to implement this using `eventDragStart`, and `eventDragStop`. See this [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/natanif/12/edit?html,css,js,output) for an example :

```
header:{
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'agendaWeek'
},
defaultDate: '2017-01-30',
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
editable: true,

eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
  let events= $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
  // allowed background events are turned into green
  // disallowed background events are turned into red
  events.forEach(function(ev) {
    if( ev.rendering == 'background') {
      if(ev.allowed) {
        ev.backgroundColor="#00FF00";
      } else {
        ev.backgroundColor="#FF0000";
      }
      // The following throws an error
      //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', ev);
    } 
  });
},

eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
  let events= $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
  // Every backgound events are turned back into blue
  events.forEach(function(ev) {
    if( ev.rendering == 'background') {
      ev.backgroundColor="#0000FF";
      // The following throws an error
     // $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', ev);
    }
  });
},

events: [
{
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2017-01-30T10:30:00',
    end: '2017-01-30T11:30:00'
  },

  {
    title: 'Allowed droppable',
    start: '2017-01-31T07:00:00',
    backgroundColor: '#0000FF',
    allowed:true,
    rendering: 'background'
  },

  {
    title: 'Disallowed droppable',
    start: '2017-01-31T10:00:00',
    backgroundColor: '#0000FF',
    allowed: false,
    rendering: 'background'
  },
```

But, it seems that I cannot use `updateEvent` within the `eventDragStart` callback, an error is thrown.

Is there a mean to update event properties on the fly, within the `eventDragStart` callback, without triggering an full event render ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It might help if you put the code in the question with the Jsbin link

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip ;-)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?